# How does script bundling work using Astro.js?

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I have created a simple Astro project, that has now two pages:

- index.astro
- dashboard.astro

If I put a console log in the `dashboard.astro` and load the index page, the script get executed.

How exactly does it work?

Comment: This question probably needs some more context to receive a good answer. Could you share the content of `index.astro` and `dashboard.astro`?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that dashboard.astro is your layout
In Astrojs you can refer to Layouts with the tag:

```
<dashboard>
   <p> some html </b>
</dashboard>
```

If you put a console log in dashboard.astro it is executed every time you use the layout tag